# Starting CPLEX with Java Program

Tags: java, cplex

I have a linear Problem that i need to solve many times with changing values.
So i had written a Program in ILOG CPLEX OPL which works fine.
Now i want to start these Program with a Java Program.
After the first Run Java should work with the output and change it.
Then another Cplex solving should start.

I tried a Windows script, which starts the Cplex Optimization Studio, starts the solving, change he data in excel and starts Cplex Studio again but this solution doesn´t works fine.
My Problem is i dont want to change the code i have written in the Ilog Cplex OPL into Java.
I just want Java to start the Solving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works by using the Information given in the CPLEX Example "mulprod"